# Error while installing Nodejs on Godaddy Shared Linux Hosting

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, godaddy, shared-hosting

I am installing Node.js on Godaddy Shared Linux Hosting by connecting to SSH via PuTTy. Getting Errors.

I ran 'curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash' command to install nvm. NVM is successfully installed as I getting response '0.34.0' on running 'nvm --version'. I am running 'nvm install node' to install Node.js.

After running this command I am getting following errors:

node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: versionGLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node) node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: versionGLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node) node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: versionGLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node) node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Runnvm use --delete-prefix v12.9.0` to unset it.

I am expecting 'nvm install node' to successfully install Node.js and all its dependencies. Actual Results (From Putty):

nvm install node Downloading and installing node v12.9.0... Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.9.0/node-v12.9.0-linux-x64.tar.gz...

############################################################ 100.0%

Computing checksum with sha256sum Checksums matched! node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: versionGLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by node) node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version CXXABI_1.3.5' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: versionGLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by node) node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: versionGLIBC_2.16' not found (required by node) node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by node)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Runnvm use --delete-prefix v12.9.0` to unset it.

Referencing this blog - https://ferugi.com/blog/nodejs-on-godaddy-shared-cpanel/

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you listed the dependencies in a JSON file?

Comment: @Chris - Sorry for the confusion with dependencies. I just want to install NodeJs successfully as of now. Please ignore dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

While Cris' answer is most likely correct in that it describes the root cause, he doesn't offer a solution compatible with the asker's environment (GoDaddy shared hosting).

According to [these instructions](https://www.codepunker.com/blog/how-to-install-node-js-and-npm-on-a-shared-cpanel-whm-hosting-account) from CodePunker, the solution is to install an older version of node.js that is compatible with whatever version of libstdc++ is installed on your GoDaddy shared host.

> - If you get an error during installation saying you don't have the required GLIBC version then you need to install an older (potentially unsupported) version of Node.js
> - To do that, execute nvm ls-remote --lts which will show you all the long term support Node.js versions that exist in the repository. Install an older one by issuing nvm install vX.X.X and then nvm use vX.X.X

The specific version of node.js that you'll need to install will depend on how outdated your shared host is. I tested this successfully with v10.13.0, but I just jumped to the oldest release in the current branch and did not test any newer versions.

You can also call GoDaddy Support and request that they update your host or move your site to a different shared host with more up-to-date libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Update your base system or compile from source (which may also require updating your base system.) No GLIBCXX_3.4.15 symbols means your libstdc++ is from 2009 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas's answer worked for me, I installed v10.13.0 using the command

```
nvm install v10.13.0
```

You need to have nvm to run the command, install by running

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash
```

All these commands where done in ssh without root access, so it will work for shared hosting.